# How to write a regular expression to get floating point numbers in Python?

Tags: python, regex

How to write the regular expression to get a floating point number in python. I want to get 55.97. from `<td nowrap="nowrap">55.97</td>`. So I gave

```
newsecond_row_data = (re.search('(?<=>)\d+|\d+.\d+',second_row_data[a]))
newsecond_row_data.group(0)

print newsecond_row_data.group(0)
```

but it gave 55 not 55.97. Plz hlp me

Thank you

Comment: Note that you should not parse HTMl with regexes and string functions. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/113586

Comment: Are all of these legal for you: `1.`, `.1`, `1`, `-1.1`, `1e-1`?

Comment: Thanks for all u'r answers,, I solved it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
newsecond_row_data = (re.search('(?<=>)\d+.\d+|\d+',second_row_data[a]))
newsecond_row_data.group(0)
```

The reason your pattern isn't working is because it sees '55', finds a match and stops further search.

Then again, I would advice not to use regex and use an XML processing library to extract text out of HTML tags (see Sudhir's answer).

Comment: Would you please be so kind to put in bold your advice for the *"I want to parse xml with regexp"* to come?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to extract data from HTML or XML take a look at the various parsers available. For this particular case, you can extract the number very easily:

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree
>>> element = ElementTree.fromstring('<td nowrap="nowrap">55.97</td>')
>>> element.text
'55.97'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newsecond_row_data = re.search('\d+\.?\d*', second_row_data[a])
print newsecond_row_data.group(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

ptn = r'[-+]?([0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)'
pat_obj = re.compile(ptn)

m = pat_obj.search(some_str)
if m:
    print(m.group(0))
```

if you have more than one floating point per string, then use *findall* instead of *match*:

```
>>> s = '3dfrtg45.2trghyui8erdftgy77.431dser'

>>> pat_obj = re.compile(ptn)
>>> v = pat_obj.findall(s)
>>> v
  ['3', '45.2', '8', '77.431']
```